# Meteor's Session.set causing duplicate the Bootstrap modal?

Tags: session, twitter-bootstrap, duplicates, modal-dialog, meteor

I am using Meteor 0.6.2.1.

I have just encountered a strange issue with Bootstrap modal when call Meteor's Session.set().

I want to show a simple modal dialogue and update some data to it when user clicks on a template instance.

I copy the Bootstrap modal example to my .html file:

```
    <body>
        {{> hello}}
        {{> alert}}
    </body>

    <template name="hello">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        {{greeting}}
        <input type="button" value="Click" />
        <br/>

        <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
        <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
    </template>

    <template name="alert">
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body…</p>
                <p>data = {{data}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

and set the data when button click:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.set("data", "abcd");
  Template.hello.greeting = function() {
    return "Welcome to use-bootstrap.";
  };
  Template.alert.data = function() {
    return Session.get("data");
  };
  Template.hello.events({
    'click input': function() {
      if (typeof console !== "undefined" && console !== null) {
        return console.log("You pressed the button");
      }
    }
  });
  Template.hello.events({
    'click .btn': function() {
      var randomId;
      randomId = Random.id();
      console.log("data = " + Session.get("data"));

      // this cause duplicate Template.alert
      Session.set("data", randomId);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    return console.log("Server Start!!");
  });
}
```

I use chrome to debug it and see the modal element will duplicate when click the button.

What's the matter about my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why this is happening but I believe it has to do with references to the modal node kept in JS code (bootstrap).

To solve it I added:

```
Template.alert.preserve(["#myModal"]);
```

From Meteor [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve):

> Preservation is useful in a variety of cases where replacing a DOM
>   element with an identical or modified element would not have the same
>   effect as retaining the original element. These include:
>
> - Input text fields and other form controls
> - Elements with CSS animations
> - Iframes
> - Nodes with references kept in JavaScript code